# What is the difference between "elif" and "else if" in shell scripting?

Tags: unix, shell, ksh

I am very new to shell scripting.

When I look at some code, written for *ksh* (`#!/bin/ksh`) I see there is `else if` as well as `elif` used in one script.

So, what is the difference between `else if` and `elif` in shell scripting?

Comment: What does the first line of the script say?  Something like `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: It says #!/bin/ksh

Comment: Please specify the shell **in your question** and **with a tag**.  There are many shells, and they all have slightly (or radically) different syntax.

Comment: I think you will want to [edit] and add sample code.  ksh supports `if`, `else`, and `elif`, but `else if` is unusual.

Comment: Nesting. `else if` starts another level and more complexity.  You want to avoid complexity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I try an answer in one sentence: If you use `elif` you deal with *one if-clause*, if you use `else if` with *two if-clauses*.

Look at these simple examples:

```
testone() {
  if [[ $CASE == 1 ]]; then
    echo Case 1.
  elif [[ $CASE == 2 ]]; then
    echo Case 2.
  else 
    echo Unknown case.
  fi
}
```

This is formally (tidy indention makes sense sometimes) one if-clause as you can see that each case is at the same hierarchy level.

Now, the same function with `else if`:

```
testtwo() {
  if [[ $CASE == 1 ]]; then
    echo Case 1.
  else
    if [[ $CASE == 2 ]]; then
      echo Case 2.
    else 
      echo Unknown case.
    fi
  fi
}
```

You have formally two cascaded if-clauses and accordingly two closing `fi` statements. Plaese note that it makes no difference here if I write `else if` in one line (as in your question) or in two lines (as in my example).

My guess why both forms are used in the same script: If you already have a complete if-clause written, but need (logic reasons) to copy/cut & paste that into an existing if-clause, you end up with `else if`. But when you write the complete if-clause from scratch you probably use the IMHO simpler-to-read form `elif`.